# Why can't I access instance properties in the Execute delegate of a DelegateCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, delegates

I'm used to using lambdas in ways apparently other than this. When I try and define a `DelegateCommand`, I have to access to non-static members of the enclosing type for the command. E.g:

```
public ICommand ShowViewCommand { get; set; } = new DelegateCommand<string>(v =>
    {
        var viewModel = new EditFormViewModel;
        var ucType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(v);
        App.SetWindowView(viewModel, ucType);
    },
v => true);
```

In the above code, in the `App.SetWindowView` call, `App` has a red squiggly underline, and on hovering over it, I am told:

> Cannot access non-static property `App` in static context.

This is not the behaviour I'm used to when using lambdas for closures. What is different here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to access an instance member within an auto-implemented property initializer. That's like trying to do so in a field initializer. Basically, you can't reference `this` even implicitly in initializers, not even within lambda expressions. Instead, you'll need to do that in a constructor:

```
public ICommand ShowViewCommand { get; set; }

public Foo() // Replace with your class name
{
    ShowViewCommand = v => new DelegateCommand<string>(v =>
    {
        var viewModel = new EditFormViewModel;
        var ucType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(v);
        App.SetWindowView(viewModel, ucType);
    });
}
```

Comment: Aaah, thank you, Jon. I got carried away with the fact that C# 6 allows for auto-property initializers. Now I remember when I last worked with WPF a few years ago I did build the commands in the constructor, and I just never realised you can't do it in an initializer. Not that you'd need it, but I wish I could have given you a bounty on this, this problem being a week long source of consternation.